# Are power supply gaskets a good idea?

Tags: power-supply, noise

I'm trying to make an Alienware machine I bought awhile ago quieter without spending a ton of money (I already did that when I bought it). It has a 750 watt power supply whose fan creates a ton of noise. I saw this product and I'm considering ordering it:

http://www.quietpcusa.com/Fansis-Anti-Vibration-Soft-Silicone-Power-Supply-Gasket-P491C1.aspx

I realize that there are questions about how to build a quiet PC but I really want to know how to quiet down this power supply fan and if this technique is actually worth trying. If you have tried it and it does work how hard is it to install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't target the fan directly, but rather helps isolate the PSU from the case.

Really, anything that will isolate one metal component from another can decrease case noise.  However, some parts may already fit more tightly than others.  So, if your PSU's vibration is a major contributor currently to your case noise, then yes, that may help.  Another big place to look at placing o-rings or other separators is the hard disk if your case doesn't have isolation already in place.

Comment: When I bought this machine it claimed that I bought some Acoustic Dampening with it so in theory the power supply should be the problem (maybe)? The complaints I've read on the internet suggest that this might be the issue. I'm not sure if the vibration is the problem or not. How could I tell?

Comment: Sadly, the best thing is the lowest tech: try to listen to see what is making the most noise.

One could also make the argument that for $6, might as well try the dampener! ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way that might tell if you're chasing PS vibration issue:

Pop the side off of the case. While the PC is running reach your (grounded) finger in and touch the PS. Now push on the PS a bit from the side or bottom (or whatever angles you have available). See if you can push it towards whatever mounts or ledges are there for it.

Does the noise change if you're touching/pushing or not? If it gets quieter or smoother when your finger is in there, then you have vibration.